# Prettier web usage

Tags: reactjs, prettier

I try to format an imput text with a react app. What I'm trying to achieve here is, this component gets a text input from props, it goes through the needed "traslator" functions, and writes the translated code on the right. I'd like this new text `const newInput = string` to be formatted via prettier. Prettier is working on web so it should be no biggie, but when I try to use the prettier.format() function it won't work.

I can't see anything that could not be used in React, but it still won't work and says that it cant resolve the imports, which can be seen on the top of the react component.
so how could I implent this, or any other advice for formatting any input text "prettier" like?

This is the original documentation for this funcion:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var formatButton = document.querySelector("#format");
    var textInput = document.querySelector("#input");
    formatButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var value = textInput.value;
      textInput.value = prettier.format(value, {
        parser: "babylon",
        plugins: prettierPlugins
      });
    });
  </script>
```

This is my code so far:

```
import React from "react";

//prettier imports
import prettier from "https://unpkg.com/prettier@2.2.1/esm/standalone.mjs";
import parserBabel from "https://unpkg.com/prettier@2.2.1/esm/parser-babel.mjs";
import parserHtml from "https://unpkg.com/prettier@2.2.1/esm/parser-html.mjs";

const Display = (props) => {
  const { input, isToggled } = props;

  // entity to HTML
  const tagsToReplace = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    "&lt;": "<",
    "&gt;": ">",
    "&nbsp;": " ",
  };

  const newInput = input.toString().replace(/&lt;|&gt;/gi, function (matched) {
    return tagsToReplace[matched];
  });

  //HTML to entity
  const tagsToReplaceBack = {
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
  };
  const changeBackInput = input.toString().replace(/<|>/gi, function (matched) {
    return tagsToReplaceBack[matched];
  });

  const formattedInput = prettier.format(newInput, {
    parser: "babel",
    plugins: [parserBabel, parserHtml],
  });


  return <div>{formattedInput}</div>;
};

export default Display;

/* {isToggled ? <div>{changeBackInput}</div> : <div>{newInput}</div>} */
```

Comment: Prettier is a compile-time library, not a run-time library.  It formats your --code-- not your markup.

Comment: Then how is this possible? https://jsbin.com/dabayidosa/edit?html,output

Comment: Hmmm, my bad.  Please excuse my ignorance, I have not seen that usage of Prettier until now!

Comment: It is all cool! I didn't want to sound too harsh either,

Answer (score 1):

I think your bundler (webpack, probably?) doesn't support importing modules from URLs. You need to install Prettier from npm as a dependency and import it the same way you import React. E.g. see this Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-worker-2oul0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Or add the prettier extension to your code editor.

Comment: Editor extensions have nothing to do with the question

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't read the question properly.